# Uncaught ReferenceError: iframeLoad is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to load an iframe function from html but I am getting an undefined on that function. I am getting a "Uncaught ReferenceError: iframeLoad is not defined". Am i missing something here?

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body onload="iframeLoad()">
<iframe id="accountroles" width="350px" height="300px"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
function iframeLoad(){

var recordID = window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId().replace(‘{‘, ”).replace(‘}’, ”).toLowerCase();

var url = "https://web.powerapps.com/webplayer/iframeapp?hideNavBar=true&source=website&appId=/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apps/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx&da&accountID="+ recordID;

document.getElementById("accountroles").src = url;

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When using inline event handling, the function must be available already at the point where you place `onload="iframeLoad()"`. Put your script into the `head`, then this should work.

Comment: @04FS I have tried that approach already and unfortunately still getting the same error.

Comment: Okay, that is probably due to your JS code containing syntax errors to begin with then - if the browser can’t parse the code properly, the function won’t be available at any time. `replace(‘{‘, ”).replace(‘}’, ”)` - those “typographic” single quotes are wrong, you need to replace them with the correct ones, `'`

Comment: I would suggest for testing remove RecordID url and simply past url = https://www.google.com and see what do you get. 
You are getting Syntax Error.

Also for getting Record Id you can use window.parent.Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId().replace(/[{}]/g, '')

Comment: You are getting this error because `iframeLoad`'s syntax is not valid , try to correct syntax error to correct this error.

Comment: @04FS Thank you! I did not notice that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, that is probably due to your JS code containing syntax errors to begin with then - if the browser can’t parse the code properly, the function won’t be available at any time.

`replace(‘{‘, ”).replace(‘}’, ”)` - those “typographic” single quotes are wrong, you need to replace them with the correct ones, `' -04FS`